# Puedo recuperar mi codigo de 2FA en heroku?

Tags: heroku

Mi problema es, que hace un tiempo formatee mi dispositivo teléfono y se me olvido hacer una copia de seguridad de mi autenticador para obtener mi código para iniciar mi sesión en Heroku, este codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como no respalde nada del autenticador de Google... mi problema es que no puedo acceder a mi cuenta de Heroku, hay alguna forma de volver a tener este código para mi autenticador, una forma de que me lo manden por correo o restablecerlo?

Answer (score 1):

A marzo 23 de 2022, la [documentación oficial](https://help.heroku.com/7IDU8QZZ/what-should-i-do-if-i-m-locked-out-of-my-heroku-account) de Heroku, lo primero que se debe revisar, dice:

> Issue
>
> You're unable to log into your Heroku account.
> Resolution
>
> Your login issue is a result of one of the following issues:
>
> Lost MFA device
>
> - If you have lost access to your MFA device, follow our instructions to recover your account.
> - If you have lost access to the MFA device and recovery code, please email support@heroku.com from the email account with the issue, it will automatically open a ticket with us.

Que en español latinoamericano diría algo como

- Si perdió acceso al dispositivo MFA (como es el caso de la pregunta), hay que seguir [las instrucciones](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/recovery-codes#mfa-verification-using-a-recovery-code). Cuando configuraste el 2FA, te debió ofrecer unos recovery codes que debiste descargar y guardar en el mismo sitio que la foto con tus abuelos y las llaves de tu casa.
- Si no tienes los recovery codes porque fuiste descuidado, tienes que escribirle a support@heroku.com desde el email usado para configurar la cuenta que quieres recuperar. Te abriran un ticket de soporte.